# Attempt to get length of null array error, How to solve?

Tags: android

I am new to android studio. my problem is when I run the code the emulator jumps out the application. but when I replace the searchtxtFile() method with a simple setName() method the application runs with no problem. I tested the application on the note4 and it worked properly, but on the emulator the listFiles() return null. I have checked the path. I ran this code on the IntelliJ Idea and it worked but on the Android Studio it has the error: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array"

Thanx in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Integer> fileNos=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ShowFileDirectory fileList = new ShowFileDirectory();
        fileList.searchtxtFiles("d://sampleb",fileNos);       -->(Line20)
    }

}
```

ShowFileDirectory.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ShowFileDirectory {

    public String setName(String name){
        return name;
    }

    public void searchtxtFiles(String folderAddress, List<Integer> fileNos2) {

        File directory;
        int fileNo=0;
        directory = new File(folderAddress);
        File[] filesInsideDirectory=directory.listFiles();
        int j=0;

        for(File file : filesInsideDirectory){         -->(Line 73)
            String extension = "";
            int i = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
            if (i > 0) {
                extension = file.getName().substring(i+1);
            }
            if (extension.equals("txt")) {
                fileNo= Integer.parseInt(file.getName().substring(0,i));
                fileNos2.add(fileNo);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the logcat is:

```
  05-16 20:47:47.990 2942-2942/com.ali.searchfiles I/Process: Sending    signal. PID: 2942 SIG: 9
  05-16 20:47:53.974 4065-4065/com.ali.searchfiles W/System: ClassLoader   referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.ali.searchfiles-1/lib/x86
  05-16 20:47:55.373 4065-4065/com.ali.searchfiles W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.ali.searchfiles-1/lib/x86
  05-16 20:47:55.461 4065-4065/com.ali.searchfiles W/art: Before Android  4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter  android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android. graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList,  android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package- private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
  05-16 20:47:55.494 4065-4065/com.ali.searchfiles D/AndroidRuntime:   Shutting down VM


                                                               ---------   beginning of crash
  05-16 20:47:55.494 4065-4065/com.ali.searchfiles E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process:       com.ali.searchfiles, PID: 4065
         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.ali.searchfiles/com.ali.searchfiles.MainActivity}:    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
          at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
          at com.ali.searchfiles.ShowFileDirectory.searchtxtFiles(ShowFileDirectory.java:73)
          at com.ali.searchfiles.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: What part of "Attempt to get length of null array" is unclear?

Comment: I don't know why listFile() returns null on the emulator while working properly on the note4.  I have checked the path. it is not empty.

Comment: Now it's a duplicate of another one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296223/listfiles-returns-null-on-android-6-0-emulator - that is the 1st in Google on "android listfiles null emulator".

Answer (score 1):

you should specify correct path for Files.

To get Externalstorage path call this function

```
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

if you are trying to access *Somefile* folder present in sd card

give `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Somefile"` as path

and before listing files always check whether the file exists or not

```
File f=new File("path");
    if(f.exists()){
        //Do file operation
    }else{
        //File not exist.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public File[] listFiles()
```

**return**
An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null** if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

As you know this may **return null** , so most probably you are supplying wrong path hence at least **provide a check for null filearray** and also **verify the path**.