# Android Version 4.3 above listFiles() always returns Null Why?

Tags: java, android

I have created a File manager App which Lists Asynchronously files from the SDCard into a Recycler View.

```
      private class AsyncFileListLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Shows the Custom Progress Dialog
        }
         @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(String... param) {

         File oneFile=new File(mother_folder);

        /*This code causes the App to Crash by Null pointer exception. 
        Happens only in Android ver 4.3 and above.WHY??*/
        File[] files = oneFile.listFiles();

         if(files.length ==0) return false;
    /*  THIS IS ALWAYS FALSE ONLY IN VERSION 4.3 and above WHY??*/

        }
        ///Rest of the code///

        }
        }
Executed thus
String DirPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

/* Correctly displays the path to External storage==Sdcard or Emulated in ver 4.4 and above*/

Toast.makeText(this,DirPath, Toast.LengthShort).show();

/* causes app to crash
 new AsyncFileListLoader().execute(DirPath);
```

I have setup correct permissions in Android manifest and List is populated in
Android ver 4.2 Phone. I check the run time permission for SD card thus

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and

Use of RUN time permissions as per this thread
[listFiles() returns null on Android 6.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296223/listfiles-returns-null-on-android-6-0-emulator)

```
int permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permissionCheck2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || permissionCheck2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                             Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_READWRITE_STORAGE);
    }
```

Check self permission returns true. I DO HAVE permission to READ and Write External storage. After 1 week of searching I have no solution. This

```
File[] files = oneFile.listFiles();
```

Returns null always, plus Using FileUtils.listFiles DOES NOT RETURN null why? Internally,I checked source code here,FileUtils uses the same ListFile...

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

There seems to be No other function which can replace listfiles()..

Thanks a heap in advance.

Comment: Executing the same in U.I Thread causes a lag but List does get populated with few File entries, even then it does not work. I tried different code using ListView Custom adapter,still cannot seem to cross this line...

Comment: Still returns Null on latest Android build.